# Apache not starting on windows 7

Tags: php, apache

I'm a beginner in PHP. When attempting to start Apache using XAMPP, I saw the following error messages in my log:

```
11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...

11:42:19 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
```

How to fix these errors?

Comment: Have you accidentally started already another server? Otherwise some other process is already using port 80 (and you should pick another one).

Comment: Reinstall and give a different port number. It will surely work!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running "Skype" from Microsoft, close it.

No just from the window, right click close/exit on the skype icon on the taskbar (in your clock) or kill the moth*** process in the task manager if you've been stucked for a while with this (it gave me some relief a few years ago), if works open skype and kill it again just to be sure.
If you're not running skype, try something from here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

If you didn't click I will quote the article here:

> The Obvious Candidates
>
> There are a number of well-known Windows programs which use port 80:
>
> IIS The most likely culprit is Microsoft Internet Information Server.
>   You can stop the service from the command line on Windows 7/Vista:
>
> net stop was /y
>
> or XP:
>
> net stop iisadmin /y
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services SSRS can remain active even if you
>   uninstall SQL Server. To stop the service:
>
> ```
> Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
> Select “SQL Server Services” in the left-hand pane.
> Double-click “SQL Server Reporting Services”.
> Hit Stop.
> Switch to the Service tab and set the Start Mode to “Manual”.
> ```
>
> Skype Irritatingly, Skype can switch to port 80. To disable it, select
>   Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection then uncheck “Use port 80 and
>   443 as alternatives for incoming connections”. What’s Using Port 80?
>
> Further detective work is necessary if IIS, SSRS and Skype are not to
>   blame. Enter the following on the command line:
>
> netstat -ao
>
> The active TCP addresses and ports will be listed — locate the line
>   with local address “0.0.0.0:80″ and note the PID value.
>
> Now right-click the task bar and select Start Task Manager. Navigate
>   to the Processes tab and, if necessary, click View > Select Columns…
>   to ensure “PID (Process Identifier)” is checked. You can now locate
>   the PID you noted above. The description and properties should help
>   you determine which application is using the port.
>
> The Task Manager allows you to kill the process, but be a little wary
>   about doing that — especially if it’s “NT Kernel & System”.
>   Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> NT Kernel & System is an essential service. Stopping it will probably
>   stop Windows in a blue-screeny-like way. Therefore, enter the
>   following at the command line:
>
> telnet 127.0.0.1 80
>
> If you’re faced with a blank screen, type “GET” and hit return. The
>   chances are, you’ll see a line stating that Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is
>   listening on port 80. If that’s the case, open Services from
>   Administrative Tools and locate “Web Deployment Agent Service”. Stop
>   the service and set it’s startup type to “Manual”.
>
> The Web Deployment Agent Service is deployed with WebMatrix and was
>   the cause of my woes. It may also be distributed with other
>   applications installed using Microsoft’s Web Platform Installer.
>
> That caused me a few frustrating hours so I hope it solves your Apache
>   or WAMP start-up problems.
>
> If you enjoyed reading this post, you’ll love Learnable; the place to
>   learn fresh skills and techniques from the masters. Members get
>   instant access to all of SitePoint’s ebooks and interactive online
>   courses, like PHP & MySQL Web Development for Beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all apaches and any web-servers you already running and then run xampp with admin privileges (click right button on app).

Answer (score 0):

Open **Service Control Manager** [Start -> "services.msc" (enter)] and Stop the Following services if they are enabled and are not important you.

- World Wide Web Publishing Service (IIS)
- Web Client
- Web Deployment Agent Service

Also check for applications like (Since PID is 4, the service must be from Microsoft so this is rare)

- Skype
- TeamViewer
- VMWare Products (In very rare case, if you have configured)