# apache 2.4 not working on a fresh installed Windows 7 64bits

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am sure this is not a replication issue. I already red about : 
[Apache not starting on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807852/apache-not-starting-on-windows-7) and [XAMPP on Windows - Apache not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794829/xampp-on-windows-apache-not-starting).

**But still I haven't found a solution to my concern** which seem to be particular.

I am on Windows 7 64bits. It is a fresh installed OS with all important updates made.

I did install xampp 7.x to work on **Drupal 7**. But apache error "**0xc000007b**".

After a lot of research I found out that new versions of Apache have a lot of difficulties working on Windows 7.

So I found "**XAMPP 1.8.2**" (a very old version), binary files that I just donwloaded, uncompressed and place on root drive "c:\". I lauched "XAMPP Control Panel", "Apache" and "MySQL". It worked fine. I could work on Drupal 7.

But now I need to work on **Drupal 8** which requires **PHP 5.5.9**. And PHP 5.5.9 requires **APACHE 2.4**.

**Attempt 1 :** New binary files for "apache" and "php"

I upgraded PHP and APACHE (downloading binary PHP and APACHE and replacing folder "php" and overidding folder "apache" on my XAMPP folder). When I launch XAMPP Control Panel, MySQL still works but Apache show this error :

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

11:42:18 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...

11:42:19 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running

**Attempt 2** : Complete new 7.x version install file

When I install a complete new version (with the xampp 7.x install file)  such as "7.x", the error message is now : 0c000007b.

How do you think I can solve this issue ?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is there anything written to the error log?

Comment: _“And PHP 5.5.9 requires APACHE 2.4”_ - that’s not even true. I think you might be confusing actual technical requirements, which what kind of pre-packaged combinations of PHP and Apache versions are offered on the web …? Btw, with a Drupal 8 I would not go for a 5pointanything PHP version any more - you should really use PHP 7. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements

Comment: Yes. A lot of information. Let me paste it. It is too long. But this is the first line : [Tue May 15 17:23:50.262044 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4524:tid 436] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: CBroe. When upgrading I directly donwloaded PHP 7.2. I just forgot to say it.

Comment: But I remember that when I wanted to install Drupal 8 on XAMPP 1.8.2 it asked for PHP 5.5.9 at least.

Comment: I am just on Windows 7 trying to figure out how to make apache's newest versions work. And everything works fine except that